# Ivy Configuration Help

Tags: apache, configuration, ivy

I've read the Ivy docs and a few other tutorials but am now trying to actually use it in a project for the first time and I am immediately presented with some roadblocks.

- For the practice, I would like to write all my own config (XML) files. Not sure where to put ivy.xml, ivyconf.xml or ivy-settings.xml: do I put them in the same directory as my build.xml?
- Besides ivy.xml, ivyconf.xml and ivy-settings.xml, are there any other config files that I should know about? Where do I place those?
- Is the IvyDE just a graphical Eclipse plugin that graphically edits ivyconf.xml or does it edit other files?

Thanks for any input - it's been surprisingly difficult finding good info on this amazing tool!

Answer (score 1):

You need only one file ivysettings.xml. You could place it beside build.xml or in any desired project directory. Optionally you could use one or more properties files for different uses.

Besides ivysettings.xml remeber about ivy cache directory. Often the best solution for all dependency resolution problems is to clean ivy cache by deleting this directory.

IvyDE allows you to resolve project dependencies inside Eclipse. IvyDE creates new classpath container named ivy.xml. Inside this container you'll find resolved libraries.
And I recomend you to use local or intranet ivy repository with Eclipse, because if resolving takes some time it will slow down loading of your projects.

For example I placed my ivysettings.xml that I use in my projects. As you can see for Eclipse there is eclipse-ivy.properties file. In this file I order Ivy to use local repository inside Eclipse. In Ant script I use remote repository by default, but there is an option to choose local repository.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ivysettings>
<settings defaultResolver="${ivy.resolver}" />
<statuses default="development">
    <status name="release" integration="false"/>
    <status name="integration" integration="true"/>
    <status name="development" integration="true"/>
</statuses>
<resolvers>
    <ssh name="remote" checkconsistency="true" checkmodified="true" descriptor="required">
        <ivy pattern="ssh://***/home/ivy/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>
        <artifact pattern="ssh://***/home/ivy/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
    </ssh>
    <filesystem name="local">
        <ivy pattern="${user.home}/.local-ivy-repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>
        <artifact pattern="${user.home}/.local-ivy-repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
    </filesystem>
</resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

elipse-ivy.properties:

```
ivy.resolver=local
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's best to create a single standardized ivy-settings.xml file and host it in a location where your builds can get to it easily.  This file will usually be the same for all projects and rarely change once you've got it setup properly.  In my development group, we host the ivy-settings.xml file on a web server so that it can easily be referenced by URL.

We build with Ant so we've also come up with a standardized ant build file which can either be hosted somewhere and imported into an Ant build script or simply copied to a project's directory if any kind of customization is necessary.

I've found that it's best to leave the Ivy configuration files as is and do any kind of customization by overriding the default values in your build scripts and/or ivy.xml files.  Just about anything you'd need to change can be overridden.  I recommend leaving the Ivy configuration files unchanged because it makes it much easier for other users to build your projects.  If you've got a bunch of changes to your config files, any other developer wishing to build your project will have to replicate those changes on their local Ivy installs just to run a local build.  That's bad mojo.

The IvyDE plugin provides editors for your ivy.xml and ivy-settings.xml files.  According to the documentation, it also provides ways to automatically download your project's dependencies, includes a custom console and a reverse dependency explorer to help troubleshoot and resolve dependency conflicts.  I only use the editors, though, so I can't vouch for the other tools.

Like Alexey, I'd recommend using a repository manager with Ivy.  Artifactory does the job nicely; It's easy to setup and rock solid once it's running.

I agree that the documentation leaves much to be desired; it took me several weeks of experimentation to really grasp how all the pieces fit together.  In the end, it was entirely worth it.  Once you've got all the kinks ironed out, a well tuned artifact management system is truly something beautiful to behold.